# Crypt/decrypt string (PHP)

Tags: php, encryption

I need to encrypt and decrypt a string. I can't use the hash because the decrypted string must be readable. I know about mcrypt but i was looking something that uses a certificate file to encrypt and decrypt.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a public/private key through openssl and is pretty simple once you use it once or twice

```
function encryptString($clearText)
{
  $keyFile=fopen("public.pem","r");
  $publicKey=fread($keyFile,8192);
  fclose($keyFile);

  openssl_get_publickey($publicKey);
  openssl_public_encrypt($clearText,$cryptText,$publicKey);
  return(base64_encode($cryptText));
}

function decryptString($cryptText)
{
  $keyFile=fopen("private.pem","r");
  $privateKey=fread($keyFile,8192);
  fclose($keyFile);

  openssl_get_privatekey($privateKey);
  $binText = base64_decode($cryptText);
  openssl_private_decrypt($binText,$clearText,$privateKey);
  return($clearText);
}
```

To generate a keypair, a brief guide is http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Transwiki:Generate_a_keypair_using_OpenSSL

In short

```
openssl rsa -pubout -in private.pem -out public.pem
```

**Update**

@keepwalking asked below how to do this from the command line and @vstm responded with a great link http://www.devco.net/archives/2006/02/13/public_-_private_key_encryption_using_openssl.php.

To summarize that page, once you have keys created, you can encrypt a text file *file.txt* and output it to *file.ssl* by using the following command.

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey public.pem -pubin -in file.txt -out file.ssl
```

To decrypt *file.ssl* to another file *decrypt.txt*, you can use the following command.

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey private.pem -in file.ssl -out decrypted.txt
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. It looks easy :) Can you translate the php functions in command line functions (openssl ....) ?

Comment: @keepwalking: check out [openssl rsautl](http://www.devco.net/archives/2006/02/13/public_-_private_key_encryption_using_openssl.php). Also check out `openssl rsautl -help` for options like the padding-scheme.

Comment: @keepwalking: do you mean using a command line function to encrypt and decrypt a string? If so take a look at vtsm's link.

Comment: I've updated the post with the command line examples that @vtsm posted. Great link.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to use **asymmetric cryptography** you either have to use the [openssl_*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-decrypt.php)-functions or the [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) if openssl is not available on your php.

The other thing is that you **can't** use a certificate like a **symmetric key**. If you have a ciphertext encrypted with a public key (a certificate contains the public key) then you have to decrypt using the private key and if the ciphertext is encrypted with the private key then you have to decrypt using the public key otherwise it won't work.